# Define cookies in base call controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two controllers:

1. parent controller inherits from Controller.

   ```
   public class ApplicationController : Controller
   {
       public ApplicationController()
       {
       }
   }
   ```
2. child controller inherits form above mentioned class.

   ```
   public class LayoutController : ApplicationController
   {
       public ActionResult Index()
       {
       }
   }
   ```

and have Initialize method in parent controller.

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
{
}
```

and my question is that when "Initialize" method called then action is not call.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you call the base method in Initialize:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
}
```

And that you don't have an `Index` action in the base controller as you already do in the child controller.

I've just tried your sample code and it worked as expected.